# Error "softlayer_virtual_guest.my_server_1: Error creating virtual guest: softlayer-go: could not SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest#createObject

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, terraform

I am testing terraform on softlayer on applying I get the below error

On applying the ssh key gets added to softlayer whereas the environment isn't created with the following error

```
softlayer_virtual_guest.my_server_1: Error creating virtual guest: softlayer-go: could not SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest#createObject, HTTP error code: '500'
```

Need help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a server, the code that I used was:

```
provider "softlayer" {
username = "set me"
api_key = "set me"
}

# Virtual Server created with existing SSH Key already in SoftLayer \
# inventory and not created using this Terraform template.
resource "softlayer_virtual_guest" "my_server_1" {
    name = "rcvtest-11"
    domain = "softlayer.com"
    ssh_keys = ["269479"]
    image = "DEBIAN_7_64"
    region = "ams01"
    public_network_speed = 10
    cpu = 1
    ram = 1024
    local_disk = true
    hourly_billing = true

}
```

However, if you continue getting this issue, you can report this in:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues

Answer (score 0):

You might provide further information of your code and since you’re using “softlayer-go” as client, it might be useful to know which of these two you’re using.
https://github.com/sudorandom/softlayer-go

https://github.com/maximilien/softlayer-go

Comment: I installed the official version from hashicorp.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to find the root cause by running:

`TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform apply`

It shows the HTTP response sent back from the SoftLayer's API